# How read json data from Postgres to HTML page with Rails 5.2?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to display a table in HTML with data stored in a json field on Postgres. Reading around, this sounds simple, but not being very conformtable with javascript front-end, I can't find the source of Failure. Here is what I did:

Created the json field 'anything' in the values_lists table:

```
ALTER TABLE dqm_app.values_lists ADD COLUMN anything json;
```

Inserted some demo data in this field:

```
update dqm_app.values_lists set anything = '[
{"Indice": "1","Type": "ABBREV","Title": "ShortName","Text": "UNDEF"},
{"Indice": "2","Type": "ALIAS","Title": "AliasName","Text": "UNKOWN"},
{"Indice": "3","Type": "ALIAS","Title": "FemaleName","Text": "UNDEFINED"}]'
where id = 0;
```

Created a javascript function and inserted it in a Rails partial to display the table:

```
<div id="jsonTable-container" onload="CreateTable()">
  <div id="jsonTable">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function CreateTable() {
    var jsonData = <%= raw this_object.anything %>;

    // Get table header
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
      for (var key in jsonData[i]) {
        if (columns.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          columns.push(key);
        }
      }
    }

    // Create the table
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // Create columns headers
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = columns[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // Add lines to the table
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
        var tableCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        tableCell.innerHTML = jsonData[i][columns[j]];
      }
    }

    // Add the table to jsonTable-container
    var tableContainer = document.getElementById("jsonTable");
    tableContainer.innerHTML = "";
    tableContainer.appendChild(table);
  }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, when displaying the page, the table does not appear.

The source code of the page contains the data as expected, but the formatting is not JSON compliant: the expected key marker is replaced by =>

```
  var jsonData = [{"Indice"=>"1", "Type"=>"ABBREV", "Title"=>"ShortName", "Text"=>"UNDEF"}, {"Indice"=>"2", "Type"=>"ALIAS", "Title"=>"AliasName", "Text"=>"UNKOWN"}, {"Indice"=>"3", "Type"=>"ALIAS", "Title"=>"FemaleName", "Text"=>"UNDEFINED"}];
```

Thus the console issues a message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id  0:688:29

How to retrieve the correct JSON formatted data from the Rails object?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you use .to_json like this: (this_object.anything).to_json

Comment: Yes, the combination of raw and .to_json returns a JSON formatted table. Thanks Finiteloop!

Comment: Awesome!  Do you mind if I add that as an answer and if so, will you accept it as the correct one?  :). I see you added an answer yourself, but it looks like you used .to_json in it.

Comment: Please do ! And stay tuned, I'll probabaly have another question about a close topic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1185081 Have a look at the .to_json method.  You can use it like this:

```rb
this_object.anything.to_json
```

the `to_json` method will create 'a JSON string for communication or serialization.'

I am not sure of your Ruby version but current stable version at the time of this post is 2.7.1.  Here is a link to Ruby version 2.0.0 for further details about the to_json method:

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was actually the formatting of the JSON data provided by Rails.
Finally, sticking to jQuery methods, the resulting code is:

```
<div id="jsonTable-container">
  <div id="jsonTable">
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  (function($) {

      var jsonData = <%= raw this_object.anything.to_json %>;

      // Get table header
      var columns = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        for (var key in jsonData[i]) {
          if (columns.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            columns.push(key);
          }
        }
      }

      // Create the table
      var table = $('<table/>', {class: 'table'});

      // Create columns headers
      var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(table);
      for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        var th = $('<th/>').appendTo(tr);
        th.html(columns[i]);
      }

      // Add lines to the table
      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(table);
        for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; j++) {
          var td = $('<td/>').appendTo(tr);
          td.html(jsonData[i][columns[j]]);
        }
      }

      // Add the table to jsonTable-container
      var tableContainer = $("#jsonTable");
      tableContainer.html("");
      tableContainer.append(table);

  }(jQuery));
</script>
```

This provides my application with a partial to display a table based on a JSON subset of data. The partial is invoked from an object show view by:

```
<%= render partial: "shared/json_show", locals: {this_object: @myObject} %>
```

This allows our users to benefit from additional anotation fields on various objects.